# SQLi query explanation

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm a beginner in the SQL injection field and I'd glad if you could help me.

**Scenario:** vulnerable web application.

Suppose you have an URL like this:

```
http://www.site1.com/cms/login.php
```

Also suppose that in order to access the site you must provide the following credentials:

> username: foo , password: bar

So given that, the above URL becomes:

```
http://www.site.com/cms/login.php?username=foo&password=bar
```

If you then inject the payload `'OR'1'='1` it changes to:

```
 http://www.site.com/cms/login.php?username=foo&password=bar'OR'1'='1
```

And that's clear enough to me, but my concern is that I was told that the corresponding 
SQL query (the one sent processed by the back-end RDBMS) should be:

```
SELECT userid
FROM CMSUsers
WHERE user = 'foo'AND password = 'bar' OR'1'='1';
```

The query is a tautology since `'1'='1'` is always TRUE.

But the payload was `'OR'1'='1` and the query's conditional statement seems to be different `OR'1'='1';` (look at `'`, there's no accent after the last 1 in the payload)

Is my doubt sensible?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

An application that is vulnerable to this kind of attack would have code similar to the following to construct the SQL query:

```
var query = "SELECT userid
FROM CMSUsers
WHERE user = '" + usernameValue + "' AND password = '" + passwordValue + "'";
```

Please note the placing of the single quotes. Everything that will be passed by the user via the `passwordValue` variable will be inserted at that location inside the single quotes.

Now, to perform the attack you need to close the single quote of the password early to be able to add that part that is always true. You would pass in something like this: `bar' OR '1' = '1`. Please note: No single quote at the beginning or end. Those come from the hardcoded query string in the application.

Inserting this value at the location of `passwordValue` above yields the following:

```
... AND password = 'bar' OR '1' = '1'
<------- A --------><------- B ---->A
```

- `A`: Hardcoded content from the program
- `B`: Content passed via the `passwordValue` variable

Comment: thanks for your reply..so you're saying that if in the address bar of the web application I put 'OR'1'='1' which means: http://www.site.com/cms/login.php?username=foo&password=bar'OR'1'='1' (quote after the last 1 on the right) Am I right in saying that the query wouldn't be executed? Sorry but I still don't understand why the exact payload 'OR'1'='1 is not entirely part of the underlying SQL query sent to the DBMS.Thanks a lot

Comment: @poi741: Please read my answer again. The complete payload is part of the query: payload: **bar'OR'1'='1**, query: ... AND password = '**bar'OR'1' = '1**';

Comment: I do apologize..you're right..Actually what I wanted to point out is the fact that another quote is part of the SQL query but that's due to hardcoding reasons I mean in order to be syntactically correct the application adds an extra quote ' and also ; Is that right?

Comment: That's correct. But that doesn't have to do anything with SQL injection. Actually, I think the semicolon wouldn't be in the program code, at least for Oracle it is invalid to send that to the database.